# Select Post with the term id

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am having a situation where i need to select a post but with where condition as shown :-

Post with both the selected terms at once.

I have tried :-

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` t 
    ON p.ID = t.object_id 
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tt 
    ON t.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
WHERE tt.term_id =86 
    AND tt.term_id=39 
GROUP BY t.object_id 
HAVING COUNT( t.term_taxonomy_id ) =2 
LIMIT 0,7
```

Here i want to select a post which is having the term id 86 & 39. These both ids are in same table.

Comment: Why are you using this condition `HAVING COUNT( t.term_taxonomy_id ) =2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relationship between these tables?

This select works, but I think you can try another way, do you have the TAG instead of the code? Anyway, check this out.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID
FROM 
    wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships t ON (p.ID = t.object_id)
WHERE 
    exists (
        SELECT tt.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt
        WHERE tt.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id 
        and tt.term_id in(86,39)
    )
group by p.ID
having count(p.ID) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN clause

```
SELECT p.ID
,p.post_title
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN 'wp_term_relationships' t ON p.ID = t.object_id
LEFT JOIN 'wp_term_taxonomy' tt ON t.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tt.term_id IN (86,39)
GROUP BY t.object_id
HAVING COUNT(t.term_taxonomy_id) = 2 LIMIT 0,7
```

Comment: i have used IN clause But its is returning for both the IDS. But i want to show the post which ahve both of these. Not atleast one from these. 86 is location & 39 is cuisine. Need to show the post which satisfy both the conditions.

Comment: How can you have table with the same column holding two values for a single row? If they are two different rows and you want to get them, then IN() or a 'OR' is the way to get them. Edit the post with table meta. It could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your where condition as follow:

```
WHERE tt.term_id in (86,39)
```

Comment: i have used IN clause But its is returning for both the IDS. But i want to show the post which ahve both of these. Not atleast one from these. 86 is location & 39 is cuisine. Need to show the post which satisfy both the conditions.

Comment: I think op wants posts that have both terms (86 and 39) for each post, in which case he can't use `IN`.

Comment: So do u want post even if either 86 or 39 returns null?